# Trying to identify a short story about a psychologist

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, psychology

I cannot remember title nor author, but a plot summary is:

A man wakes up in a strange room, goes to the door and find it locked.  There is a computer terminal in the room.  He sits at the terminal and quickly finds out that it contains a psychological diagnostic "artificial intelligence" program.  He is a psychologist, and the program is based on his own theories, which he has since repudiated.

That repudiation is a threat to his colleagues and the reason he's in the cell.  He attempts to fool the program by remembering his own work, but the stress of keeping his answers consistent is too much for him and he is sedated again.

I think I read it in the early 1980s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you could be describing "Conversational Mode" by Graham Leman from 1972. It's written as a dialogue between a psychiatrist and a computer diagnostic program he had helped to develop.

Edit: you can find it in [these](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57451) publications.

The beginning of the story:

> where am i ?

> TO START CONVERSATION U MUST ENTER ‘START’ ON THE TERMINAL KEYBOARD AND WAIT FOR THE INSTRUCTION ‘READY’ ON THE DISPLAY AT THE FOOT OF YOUR BED ф

> start

> 0321 /42 READY ф

> who are you ?

> HARDWARE IBM 490/80; SOFTWARE JOHNS HOPKINS PSYCHOTHERAPEUTIC PROGRAM XIXB, WRITTEN IN PSYCHLAN VII DIALECT 324 (SEE MANUAL IN YOUR BEDSIDE CUPBOARD); MIDDLEWARE MACHINE-INDEPENDENT OPERATING SYSTEM CALTECH PIDGIN XVIII (SEE MANUAL IN YOUR BEDSIDE CUPBOARD) ф

Comment: I don't think that's it, but there are enough details to merit checking.  Thanks.  (Interesting that in 1972 "U" for "you" was portrayed as acceptable for such an application.)

Comment: Hmmm, it may well be that my memory is significantly distorted by the years, but I don't remember my story being the actual computer log.  Found copy at http://en.booksee.org/book/1735431

Comment: @WGroleau I found this question because I was looking for the same story.  This (Conversational Mode) is certainly the story I read.  Never came across another like it.